# Get DPI information of PDF image Python

Tags: python, resolution, dpi

I have pdf file in which an image is embedded in it how i can get the DPI information of that particular image using python.
i tried using "pdfimages" popler-util it gives me the height and width in pixels.

But how i can get the DPI of image from that.

Answer (score 3):

Like the PostScript format or the EPS format, a PDF file has no resolution because it is a vectorial format. All you can do is retrieving the image dimensions in *pt* (or pixels):

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfReader
import io


with (io.open(path, mode="rb") as f):
    input_pdf = PdfReader(f)
    media_box = input_pdf.pages[0].mediabox

min_pt = media_box.lower_left
max_pt = media_box.upper_right

pdf_width = max_pt[0] - min_pt[0]
pdf_height = max_pt[1] - min_pt[1]
```

Comment: the question is about image dpi and not pdf page dpi itself

Answer (score 0):

`pdfimages` returns images dpis too:

```
> pdfimages -list pdf.pdf
page   num  type   width height color comp bpc  enc interp  object ID x-ppi y-ppi size ratio
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   1     0 image    1308  1675  rgb     3   8  jpeg   no        17  0   150   150  166K 2.6%
```

`x-ppi` is what u need and its enough for most cases; also I found that this method works very fast

I've just wrote some wrapper on this shell command to run it and extract some information using Python classes

Comment: @KJ these are usually same things on normal pdfs; sure u can construct different digital pdf cases but in real documents it does not matter

Answer (score 0):

In a PDF the image ppi is NOT dpi. It is simply the scale it has ben injected as.

Images in a PDF have no knowledge of DPI they are simply number of pixel/ vectors per area.

This image is one dot per pixel 3 pixels wide by three high so you can see it **HE[image]RE** in a very powerful zoom it has red blue and 2 BLACK corners and in here above it is as a PNG nominally scaled as 96 DPI, Below the same PNG is in a PDF at 72pt per inch and one of the black corners is now white (remember it is a PNG thus can have alpha colours, where inversion applies)

[image]

Here is the external report which says that it is now scaled at 3 PPI which is correct but it is NOT the source nominal 96 DPI

```
pdfimages -list "colours (decom).pdf
page   num  type   width height color comp bpc  enc interp  object ID x-ppi y-ppi size ratio
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   1     0 image       3     3  rgb     3   8  image  no         6  0     3     3   24B  89%
   1     1 smask       3     3  gray    1   1  image  no         6  0     3     3    4B 400%
```

A ppi report is a NOTIONAL suggestion based on say stored width divided by stored pixels, SO NOT the source resolution, which is an unknown.

You could extract the image as 300 DPI and it may be similar resolution to source or 72 DPI it does not matter, a report of 1-1000-whatever is no value simply 3 is its current internal placement PPI scale.

To get the RGB image back as perfect pixels we can run `pdfimages -png in.pdf out` and the export will be exactly what went in except the resolution is now 72 DPI and it's 24bits without the transparency.

[image]

And here is that companion second part with the alpha layer (also 72 DPI for registration).

[image]

**SOME jpeg may still have source resolution in their header IF it was not removed during injection.**